# Apply TensorFlow Transform to transform/scale features in production

Tags: python, tensorflow, apache-beam, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-transform

## Overview

I followed the following guide to write TF Records, where I used `tf.Transform` to preprocess my features. Now, I would like to deploy my model, for which I need apply this preprocessing function on real live data.

## My Approach

First, suppose I have 2 features:

```
features = ['amount', 'age']
```

I have the `transform_fn` from the Apache Beam, residing in `working_dir=gs://path-to-transform-fn/`

Then I load the transform function using:

`tf_transform_output = tft.TFTransformOutput(working_dir)`

I thought that the easiest way to serve in in production was to get a numpy array of processed data, and call `model.predict()` (I am using Keras model).

To do this, I thought [`transform_raw_features()`](http://transform_raw_features) method is exactly what I need.

However, it seems that after building the schema:

```
raw_features = {}
for k in features:
    raw_features.update({k: tf.constant(1)})

print(tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(raw_features))
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'indices'
```

Now, I am assuming this happens because I used `tf.VarLenFeature()` when I defined schema in my `preprocessing_fn`.

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    outputs = inputs.copy()

    for _ in features:
        outputs[_] = tft.scale_to_z_score(outputs[_])
```

And I build the metadata using:

```
RAW_DATA_FEATURE_SPEC = {}
for _ in features:
    RAW_DATA_FEATURE_SPEC[_] = tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32)
    RAW_DATA_METADATA = dataset_metadata.DatasetMetadata(
    dataset_schema.from_feature_spec(RAW_DATA_FEATURE_SPEC))
```

So in short, given a dictionary:

`d = {'amount': [50], 'age': [32]}`, I would like to apply this `transform_fn`, and scale these values appropriately to input into my model for prediction. This dictionary is exactly the format of my `PCollection` before the data is processed by the `pre_processing()` function.

## Pipeline Structure:

```
class BeamProccess():

def __init__(self):

    # init 

    self.run()


def run(self):

    def preprocessing_fn(inputs):

         # outputs = { 'id' : [list], 'amount': [list], 'age': [list] }
         return outputs

    with beam.Pipeline(options=self.pipe_opt) as p:
        with beam_impl.Context(temp_dir=self.google_cloud_options.temp_location):
            data = p | "read_table" >> beam.io.Read(table_bq) \
            | "create_data" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessFn())

            transformed_dataset, transform_fn = (
                        (train, RAW_DATA_METADATA) | beam_impl.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(
                    preprocessing_fn))

            transformed_data, transformed_metadata = transformed_dataset

            transformed_data | "WriteTrainTFRecords" >> tfrecordio.WriteToTFRecord(
                    file_path_prefix=self.JOB_DIR + '/train/data',
                    file_name_suffix='.tfrecord',
                    coder=example_proto_coder.ExampleProtoCoder(transformed_metadata.schema))

            _ = (
                        transform_fn
                        | 'WriteTransformFn' >>
                        transform_fn_io.WriteTransformFn(path=self.JOB_DIR + '/transform/'))
```

And finally the `ParDo()` is:

```
class ProcessFn(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):

        yield { 'id' : [list], 'amount': [list], 'age': [list] }
```

Comment: Is the code part of the `ParDos`? Can you post the whole `ParDo`, and maybe the pipeline? Sometimes errors like this can happen when you return a single object from a `ParDo` instead of a list.

Comment: @Anton Added my pipeline structure. My code is actually not part of the ParDos. It is separate, since at serving time, I will not have access to the Beam. Hence I wanted to use the transforms and transform raw dictionaries that I feed myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the snippet

```
raw_features = {}
for k in features:
    raw_features.update({k: tf.constant(1)})

print(tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(raw_features))
```

In this code you construct a dictionary where the values are tensors.  Like you said, this won't work for a `VarLenFeature`.  Instead of using `tf.constant` try using `tf.placeholder` for a a `FixedLenFeature` and `tf.sparse_placeholder` for a `VarLenFeature`.

Comment: Currently So beam input for preprocessing differs from input at serving time? I go around the problem by feeding `tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0], [1,0]], values=[20,30], dense_shape=[2,1])` directly. However, when the beam applies the transform. I only feed the dictionary: `d = { 'age': [20, 30] }`. But now, I need to manually transform these dictionaries to sparse tensors, and then use the transform graph on them, and finally turn them into dense tensors which can be fed into the model. Also I don't understand why the raw input into Beam is 1D, while sparse placeholders are 2D